# How to show lists new form to visitor?

Tags: list-view

Can visitor access the SharePoint 2013 list app new form? I am trying to show lists new form in one page using web part, but that page is not accessible to visitor. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To allow users to create a new list item, u need to give them at least contribute permission level. There is no workaround to this

Comment: Why would you wanna give a visitor access to a list newform? They won't be able to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

By "visitor" do you mean a person with visitor acces? If yes, then you can't. You need to give a person rights to add new items to your list.

If a person has sufficient access, just open your new item page in Edit mode or from SharePoint designer, and set it as your site's home page.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous users can only "read" - view lists, libraries and items, but can not make changes. If you want to enable anonymous access, please refer to [this article](https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site).

If you want to set anonymous access not to whole site but just for one list, read [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90012/permission-to-anonymous-user-for-document-of-document-library).